# Seeing errors when trying to start server for django/python website

Tags: python, django, git, heroku

Am just making my first Python/Django website and am working in a small team and we're all contributing to GIT HUB.  When I closed my laptop this morning everything was working fine.  I know my colleagues updated the code so I ran GIT PULL... and it finished saying:

```
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
```

I then kicked off the server running python manage.py runserver however got the below message.

```
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
[13/Nov/2015 19:48:44] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 175098
[13/Nov/2015 19:48:44] "GET /static/debug_toolbar/css/toolbar.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[13/Nov/2015 19:48:44] "GET /static/debug_toolbar/js/jquery_post.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[13/Nov/2015 19:48:44] "GET /static/debug_toolbar/js/jquery_pre.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[13/Nov/2015 19:48:44] "GET /static/debug_toolbar/js/toolbar.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[13/Nov/2015 19:48:44] "GET /static/debug_toolbar/img/ajax-loader.gif HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[13/Nov/2015 19:48:44] "GET /static/debug_toolbar/css/print.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0
^Cunknown-6c-40-08-a3-53-04:src vaijoshi$
```

I'll be honest, I have no idea where to start ... I found the below on another stack overflow question:

"An HTTP 304 response means "I don't need to fetch it again, since it hasn't changed since I got it last". So if that's the response code you got, you may not have a problem at all. Or did you mean 404 (not found)?

In any event, you normally don't serve static files with Django directly; you do it through your front-end server. On Heroku, they have a special app and setup to help with that. You can read about it at: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets."

However am unsure how relevant the above is as I am also receiving the attached screenshot when I tried to refresh the page ...

[image: screenshot of what I get when I restart server]

HTML: home.html

```
    {% extends 'layouts/base.html' %}
{% load static from staticfiles %}

{% block extrahead %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/home.css' %}">
<style>
body {
    background-image:url('{% static 'img/Homepage/Arianna.jpg' %}');
}
</style>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<div class="container">
    <!--row 1-->
    <header class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <div id="title">
                <p>
                    <a href="{% url 'home' %}"><em><span style="color=#465C63">Artists</span> Decoded</em></a>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-6"></div>

        <div id="loginbar">
            <div class="col-xs-1">
                <div id="createprofile">
                    <p>
                        <a href="/registerprofessional" class="forartists">Artists</a>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-1">
                <div id="signup">
                    <p>
                        <a href="/registeruser">Clients</a>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-1">
                <div id="login">
                    <p>
                        <a href="/login">Log In</a>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>

    <!--row 2-->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 center-block">
            <div class="welcome_text_div center-block"></div>
            <div class="how_it_works_box text-center">
                <a href="{% url 'how_it_works' %}" id="how_it_works">How It Works</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
<!-- end container -->
{% endblock %}
```

howitworks.html:

```
{% extends 'layouts/base.html' %}
{% load static from staticfiles %}

{% block extrahead %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/home.css' %}">
<style>
body {
    background-image:url('{% static 'img/Homepage/Arianna.jpg' %}');
}
</style>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<div class="container">
    <!--row 1-->
    <header class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <div id="title">
                <p>
                    <a href="{% url 'home' %}"><em><span style="color=#465C63">Artists</span> Decoded</em></a>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-6"></div>

        <div id="loginbar">
            <div class="col-xs-1">
                <div id="createprofile">
                    <p>
                        <a href="/registerprofessional" class="forartists">Artists</a>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-1">
                <div id="signup">
                    <p>
                        <a href="/registeruser">Customers</a>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-1">
                <div id="login">
                    <p>
                        <a href="/login">Log In</a>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>

<img src="'{% static 'img/Homepage/howitworks.png' %}'" alt="How It Works" width="80%">

</div>
URL.py

    from django.conf.urls import include, url
    from django.contrib import admin
    from django.conf import settings

    from .views import home, terms_and_conditions, how_it_works


    urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
        url(r'^admin/docs/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),
        url(r'^accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),

        url(r'^terms-and-conditions/$', terms_and_conditions, name='terms_and_conditions'),
        url(r'^how-it-works/$', how_it_works, name='how_it_works'),
        url(r'^$', home, name='home'),
    ]

    if settings.DEBUG:
        from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
        from django.conf.urls.static import static

        urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
        urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

ABOVE ADJUSTED AND RUNNING SERVER NOW WORKS.  However, on clicking on 'How it works' instead of a page opening, I am getting this:[image]

There are 3 of us who are currently contributing to the site development and all 3 of us are novice.  My colleague did say he deployed the app to heroku, I'm not familiar with it though know what it does.. I'm unsure on how all of the dots join together.  Please assist.  If it helps, our front end has been built using Bootstrap.

Thanks

Comment: You are calling a url named 'howitworks' ina wrong way, please show your html where you call you url.

Comment: show the line no. 59

Comment: Hi @Gocht thanks for getting back to me.  Adding it now above...

Comment: @AyushShanker <a href="{% url 'howitworks' %}" id="how_it_works">How It Works</a>

Comment: Ok, your url is named '`how_it_works`' you need to use '`{% url 'how_it_works' %}`'

Comment: @Gocht cool I tried and that worked. Makes sense now.  However on clicking on the 'How it works' page I received another error.  See above.

Comment: @Gocht never mind ... i guess it means I have an unclosed tag in my template :) baby steps but am getting there...

Comment: You have an error calling to the block tag, please show more of your how it works page html and will try to give you a full answer in the answers section

Comment: @Gocht sure, I have added the full home.html code and howitworks.html code beneath it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About your first problem:

You are using `{% url 'howitworks' %}` in your `.html` file, but you have defined  your url like this:

```
...
url(r'^how-it-works/$', how_it_works, name='how_it_works'),
...
```

Note that the url's name is '`how_it_works`' so you need to use `{% url 'how_it_works' %}` instead of `{% url 'howitworks' %}`.

About your second problem.

The error message you're getting is clear, you have an unclosed tag `block`, check out your code and verify all your tag are closed.